# Updating table with custom numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Below is my dataset, which contains four columns id, year, quarter, and price.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,1,2),
                 year = c(2010,2010,2011,2011),
                 quarter = c("2010-q1","2010-q2","2011-q1","2011-q2"),
                 price = c(10,50,10,50))
```

Now I want to expand this dataset for 2012 and 2013. First, I want to **copy rows** for 2010 and 2011 and paste them below, and after that, replace these values for years and quarters with 2012 and 2013 and also quarters with 2012-q1,2012-q2,2013-q1 and 2013-q2.
So can anybody help me with how to solve this and prepare the table as the table below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(year = year + 2, quarter = paste0(year, "-q", id)) %>%
  bind_rows(df, .)

  id year quarter price
1  1 2010 2010-q1    10
2  2 2010 2010-q2    50
3  1 2011 2011-q1    10
4  2 2011 2011-q2    50
5  1 2012 2012-q1    10
6  2 2012 2012-q2    50
7  1 2013 2013-q1    10
8  2 2013 2013-q2    50
```